# How to mount a TO-200AB

Tags: scr

I'm looking into high power SCRs. The two common cases i'm finding are TO-209AB and TO-200AB.

The TO209AB are straight forward to mount and connect.

[image]

The other, TO-200AB is strange looking and doesn't provide any mounting information. It appears that these would mount into some kind of socket but i'm not finding what that socket should be.

[image]

How is a TO-200AB mounted and connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pucks or PUK mnt. are intended to be torqued to a heatsink to specs. for high current and low Rth.

(see thermal and mechanical specification)

[www.vishay.com/docs/95544/mounting.pdf](http://www.vishay.com/docs/95544/mounting.pdf)
[image]

Comment: Do you have any examples of how this is actually done? Pictures would be great!

Comment: no. look for vendor specs and decide if heatsink needs to be electrically insulated with nylon washers around centre screw and mica washer or not.

Comment: Torque it to a heat sink is not a sufficient answer. This device has no threads or screw holes. It can be electrified up to 1000V and conduct up 1000A. The two end surfaces are the connections, so this thing has to be pinched by two conductive objects that don't touch. The question still remains, how?

Comment: fair comment... but poor attempt to search on your part

Comment: I was not finding anything because i was searching for a socket. Thank you for completing you answer.

Comment: -1 for a link-only answer.

Answer (score 3):

The To-200AB doesn't mount into a socket.

[Tony Stewart gave you the correct link for mounting instructions](http://www.vishay.com/docs/95544/mounting.pdf) for the TO-200AB.

You must clamp it between two heat sinks using a particular clamp that provides a set amount of force (spring loaded.)  Two examples are mentioned, Bellville washer type clamp and spring bar clamp.

From the way it looks, the heatsinks provide the electrical connection to two sides of the device.

---

[This is an example of a spring bar clamp.](http://www.westcode.com/prodlit/PA2.pdf)

[image]

[The datasheet for the devices list the needed clamping force.](http://www.vishay.com/docs/94398/vs-st230cseries.pdf)  The linked example datasheet for the VS-ST230C Series Thyristor lists the mounting force as 4900 Newtons.